# Functionality/Plugin to make calls, in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, mobile-application

I am developing a application using phone gap and JQM, in my application i want there is a list of dealers present and in front of each dealer a "call" button is present, now if the user presses the call button, the device should automatically call that particular number, i have the numbers associated, i just don't know if there is a way you can make calls, in PhoneGap

Answer (score 0):

I've no chance to test it but have you tried

```
<a href="tel:+000-0000000">Call me</a>
```

[source](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.phonegap/4890)

Also have a look at the [google discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/26f2c56414219d50). Simon is somewhat involved in the Phonegap project and his posts are usually quite helpful for me.